# Google API doc revision history: cannot get all metadata

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

Using google's api, I am trying to get all revision metadata for a gdoc.  Specifically, I want user data, i.e. who made what revision to a document.  Here is my code:

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'path to my .json file'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes = SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

doc_id = "my doc id"

document_revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId=doc_id).execute()
```

When I execute the code, I only get limited metadata, shown below:

```
{'kind': 'drive#revisionList',
 'revisions': [{'kind': 'drive#revision',
   'id': '1',
   'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
   'modifiedTime': '2020-09-25T03:18:42.727Z'},
  {'kind': 'drive#revision',
   'id': '92',
   'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
   'modifiedTime': '2020-09-25T03:22:53.980Z'},
  {'kind': 'drive#revision',
   'id': '246',
   'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
   'modifiedTime': '2020-09-25T04:59:20.259Z'}]}
```

Why can't I get the full metadata as shown here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, how about using the value of `fields`? When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
document_revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId=doc_id).execute()
```

#### To:

```
document_revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId=doc_id, fields='*').execute()
```

- When `*` is used, all metadata are returned. For example, when `revisions(id,modifiedTime)` is used for `fields`, the metadata of id and modified time are returned.

#### Reference:

- [Revisions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)